# convert unacceptable cells to " " (blank, or skip)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am doing the below, currently; successfully dropping the entire row, with my `if in`  - but it turns out, i don't need to drop the entire row.. How can I handle cells specifically.

---

How could I **keep the same logic but apply to** the **CELL... convert the `N/A,` `NaT`, and `NaN` cells to blank?**

```
for row in excel_data.itertuples():
    ids = row.IDS
    total_records += 1

    if ids in ("", " ", "N/A", "NaT", "NaN", None) or math.isnan(ids):
        # print(f"Invalid record: {row}")
        num_invalid_records += 1
        # total_invalid = num_invalid_records + dup_count
        excel_data = excel_data.drop(excel_data.index[row.Index])
        # continue
    else:
        num_valid_records += 1
        continue
```

**My data looks like this:** *(below)* 
As you can see there are N/As that seem to translate as 'NaTs' or Nan's in Pandas - I would just like to convert these to blank or " " or even skip somehow if possible....

[image]

In pandas the **dataframe** will **output** like this *(i omitted some sensitive entries, but you get the idea)*.

```
External_Referral='qweryt', Transitions_Planning='NF', Date_ICP_ICT_Signed_by_Member__Caregiver=datetime.date(2019, 1, 10), Date_Refused_Final_Signature_of_ICP=datetime.date(2019, 1, 10), Refused_Final_Signature_Comments='concern', Intervention_Outcome='Successful Contact', Monthly_Member_Contact_Y_N='Yes', Monthly_Member_Contact_Date=datetime.date(2019, 1, 10), Special_Projects_HHB_program='Baby Box Given', ICT_Meeting_Dates_Additional_Comments=NaT, _20='Yes', Date=datetime.date(2019, 2, 12), Targeted_Case_Management_Referral='Yes')
```

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you add some example data (5-10 rows is sufficient) and add expected output as well? Heres more information on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: How is this question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Erfan I have added it. As you can see there are N/As that seem to translate as 'NaTs' or Nan's in Pandas - I would just like to convert these to blank.....

Comment: @PeterGibbons did you read the link I gave you? Its 2 min work to make a reproducable dataframe and its for your own benefit, since we can answee your question better. I have the solution. Just waiting for you to provide a dataframe which I can answer your question with

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, i just added my dataframe. That helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that excel_data is a Pandas Dataframe.

If so, you can use the [Pandas function fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on your IDS column.